# remote server enable via code

Tags: pi-3, display, windows-iot, server

I have Pi3 model B running Windows 10, I also have a laptop running Windows 10. I want to start the remote server in Pi3, via code, because I don't have an HDMI display. Is this possible?

Comment: IIRC this can be done via SSH.

Answer (score 1):

Yes sure, you can isntall the Windows IoT Remote desktop client on your Windows 10 machine from the [app store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/store/p/windows-iot-remote-client/9nblggh5mnxz)

Then you will see on your Windows 10 desktop the exact screen as it would be on HDMI

[image]